# How to call particular chunks from a child to a parent document using knitr?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm aware that is possible to call child documents to a parent document. However, I was wondering if it is posible to call some particular chunks of the child, instead of the full document.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

How to precisely implement it depends on whether 1) the child document is actually included in the parent document and some of its chunks are to be reused in the parent or 2) you want to selectively use chunks from one "child" document in another "parent" document. <sub>(I use quotes to emphasize that in this case there is no actual parent-child relation.)</sub>

Case 1 is trivial. All chunks from the parent document are "known" in the child document and vice versa. Reusing chunks from the child document in the parent document therefore boils down to simple [chunk reuse](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/), i.e. an empty chunk with some label inherits a previous chunk's code with the same label.

Case 2 requires to read the chunks from the child document without actually including the child document. The following chunk in the main document does the trick:

```
<<hiddenChild, echo = FALSE>>=
invisible(knitr::knit_child("mychild.Rnw", quiet = TRUE))
@
```

This evaluates the child document but neglects all of its output. After that, we are back in case 1 and can reuse chunks from the child.

However, in my opinion case 2 is dissatisfactory. The whole child document will be evaluated, which may take some time and have unwanted side effects. I therefore suggest a different workflow, building on [code externalization](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/). All chunks (or at least chunks that are used in both documents) are placed in an R file which is structured like [knitr-example 113](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/113-foo.R):

```
# ---- test-a ----
1 + 1
x = rnorm(10)

# ---- test-b ----
mean(x)
sd(x)
```

In the main document, use `knitr::read_chunk` in an early chunk to read that R file. This will parse the R file into two (not yet evaluated) chunks `test-a` and `test-b`. These can then be reused in *both* documents. (If the child document must be compileable standalone, then add `read_chunk` to the child as well. Reading the same chunks twice when knitting the main document does not hurt.)